# Windows 10 crashes the computer on SDR

Tags: windows-10, crash, gaming

Just noticed it after it happened pretty frequently.
Windows 10 is crashing and restarting the PC each and every time I use Nvidia SDR resolution.
I read it was a windows 10 bug but I didn't check if it was fixed in the creators update.
I am using a high-end PC - Intel core i7 - 7700K 4.2 GHZ
Asus Maximus IX Code motherboard
GTX 1080 FTW
Water-based cooling system
and a 650W power supply.

Comment: What file is responsible ? Is it nvlddmkm.sys ?

Comment: I don't know exactly because this is happening mainly when I am gaming, It will crash the PC and restart.

Comment: What symptoms beyond just "crashing" are there? Is it BSOD, anything in system logs, any message, just a total lockdown, or does the display flicker. These things can help someone identify the issue for you.

Comment: I feel the heat of the computer, but it's pretty much normal when dealing with high graphics at full power, it's not something that should affect unless pushed over the limits. The computer just shuts off and restarts, which may be because of power supply (650W is more then enough for GTX 1080 and i7 7700k processor) or overheat (my RAM memory is 32 GB so memory overload cannot possibly happen). Didn't check the system logs and not message appear. For the situation at hand, just a total lockdown.

Comment: Try updating the chipset drivers and use 381.89 as video driver (latest one is not that good).

Comment: I am already at 382.05, they updated twice in less then a week

Comment: I think I am going to upgrade my power supply to EVGA G2 850W and settle it done..